# Confusion with using Break and nested if statements

Tags: powershell

where does a break bring me? If I have nested if's does a break bring me 1 up or all the way out?

It this example below if I want to get to the `if ($UTC)` how do I get there?

```
If ($UTC) {
    If (!$NoSeperators) {  
        If ($JustDate) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-") + ($ReportNameExt))
            Break 
        }

        IF ($NoSeconds) { 
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmm-") + ($ReportNameExt))
            Break
        }

        $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-") + ($ReportNameExt))
      
    }
    # Remove dash and underscores with NoSeperators switch.
    IF ($NoSeperators) {
        IF ($JustDate) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ($ReportNameExt))
            Break
        }

        IF ($NoSeconds) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmm") + ($ReportNameExt))
            Break
        }

        $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmss") + ($ReportNameExt))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code, just use the if-else your task would be done.

```
If ($UTC) {
    If (!$NoSeperators) {  
        If ($JustDate) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
        elseif ($NoSeconds) { 
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmm-") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
        else {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy_MM_ddThhmmss-") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
    }
    # Remove dash and underscores with NoSeperators switch.
    else {
        IF ($JustDate) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
        elseif ($NoSeconds) {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((get-date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmm") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
        else {
            $FullPath = Join-AnyPath $DirectoryName ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmss") + ($ReportNameExt))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**The [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) and [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Continue) statements *only* apply to**:

- *loop statements*: [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach), [`while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_While), [`do`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Do)
- [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statements
- the rarely used [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement

Notably, they are *not* meaningful in `if` statements and *in the pipeline* (such as in script blocks passed to the `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` cmdlets).

**Outside these contexts, `break` and `continue` should be *avoided*, because their behavior is *treacherous***:

- PowerShell looks up the call stack for an enclosing loop / `switch` statement *anywhere* and breaks out of *that*.

  - For instance, if you use `break` outside of a relevant statement but the script that called yours happens to have called from inside a relevant statement, your script is exited *as a whole*, and the *calling* script's statement is broken out of.
- If there is no such statement on the entire call stack, *execution ends quietly altogether*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Unless the code snippet in your question is embedded in a `break`-relevant statement (that you're not showing), your script will exit *as a whole* when `break` executes - either way, this is not what you intended.

To solve your problem, **use *single* [`if` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_If) with `elseif` branches**, as shown in [Ashish Jain's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68868047/45375).

Comment: [Everything about `if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-7.4)