# Return not behaving as i expect

Tags: powershell, linq

I'm solving [the problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52bc74d4ac05d0945d00054e/train/csharp)

here is the solution i made first

```
using namespace System.Linq
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
 
class kata{
    static [string] FirstNonRepeatingLetter ([String]$string_){
        [Enumerable]::GroupBy([char[]]$string_, [func[char, char]]{$args[0]}).Foreach{
            if ($_.Count -eq 1){
                Write-Debug ($_.key)
                return $_.Key 
            }
        }
        return "~~~"
    }
}
 
Write-Debug ([kata]::FirstNonRepeatingLetter("stress"))
```

it's return

```
DEBUG: t
DEBUG: r
DEBUG: e
DEBUG: ~~~
```

this is not what i expected
I try this

```
using namespace System.Linq
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
 
class kata{
    static [string] FirstNonRepeatingLetter ([String]$string_){
        $groups = [Enumerable]::GroupBy([char[]]$string_, [func[char, char]]{$args[0]})
        foreach ($group in $groups)
        {
            if ($group.Count -eq 1){
                return $group.Key 
            }
        }
        return "~~~"
    }
}
 
Write-Debug ([kata]::FirstNonRepeatingLetter("stress"))
```

and then what I wanted to see

```
DEBUG: t
```

and now I don't understand why these codes work differently...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're executing `return` inside a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) you've passed to the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) method:

- **In script blocks passed as *arguments*** (as opposed to blocks that are integral to statements such as `if` and `foreach`), **`return` *exits only the block itself*.**
- Therefore, your `.ForEach()` enumeration *continues* after each `return`; that is, while execution *inside* the script block is terminated, execution continues with the next `.ForEach()` iteration.

There actually is *no* direct way to stop the enumeration of `.ForEach()` (by contrast, the related [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) has an optional parameter that accepts a `'First`' to stop enumerating after finding the first match).

You have two options:

- Set a Boolean flag inside your script block to indicate whether a result has been found, and exit the script block right away if the flag is found to be set.

  - The obvious downside to this is that the enumeration always runs to completion.
- Use a *dummy loop* so that you can repurpose a [`break` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break) to break out of the loop and thereby also out of the `.ForEach()` enumeration.

  - Note: Without the dummy loop, `break` would be looking up the entire call stack for a loop to break out of; if it finds none, execution would terminate *overall* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68867996/45375) for more information.
- Either way, you need a `return` statement *outside* to script block in order to return a value from your *class method*.

Here's how to implement the dummy-loop approach:

```sh
using namespace System.Linq
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
 
class kata{
    static [string] FirstNonRepeatingLetter ([String]$string_){
      $result =  '~~~'
      do {  # dummy loop
        [Enumerable]::GroupBy([char[]]$string_, [func[char, char]]{$args[0]}).Foreach{
          if ($_.Count -eq 1){
                Write-Debug ($_.key)
                $result = $_.Key
                break  # break out of the dummy loop
            }
        }
      } while ($false)
      return $result
    }
}
 
Write-Debug ([kata]::FirstNonRepeatingLetter('stress'))
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but, `return` isn't **just** "*syntactical sugar*" as some people like to call it? There's an actual use for it?

Comment: @mklement0 really like your high quality answers, cheers +1

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, no, `return` isn't just syntactic sugar, because it controls the execution flow (exits the current scope). `return $obj` is syntactic sugar, for `$obj; return`, with the `return` possibly being optional, if `$obj` isn't followed by other (output-relevant) statements.

Comment: Thank you, @Avshalom, I appreciate the nice feedback, and I'm glad you find the answers useful.

Comment: Ahhh! Makes sense. Thank you! I find your explanations clearer to understand rather than the MS Docs themselves; the reason why I comment alot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with doing that without a class, but a normal function instead, this should work:

```
function Get-FirstNonRepeatingCharacter ([string]$string) {
    ($string.ToCharArray() | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 1 } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
}

Get-FirstNonRepeatingCharacter "sTress"  # --> T
```

Comment: thanks, but here I am interested not in the solution, but in understanding the behavior of this code.